# Can I make tweaks to a color-theme per mode?

Tags: emacs, themes, color-scheme

I'm using Emacs 23.2.1 from Ubuntu 11.04. I've installed [purcell's port of the Solarized color-theme](https://github.com/purcell/color-theme-sanityinc-solarized), but I'd like to adjust some of the faces to make my Python buffers look more like [the Solarized Vim screenshot](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/img/screen-python-dark.png). It's easy enough to edit the color-theme so that my preferred colors are always used, but that would also change them in C mode and I want to avoid that.

Specifically, here's the default setting for the builtin-face:

```
(font-lock-builtin-face ((t (:foreground ,green))))
```

In Python mode - and only Python mode - I'd like to use this instead:

```
(font-lock-builtin-face ((t (:foreground ,blue))))
```

I'd ideally like to make this change by patching some logic into the color-theme definition so that I can send my adjustments upstream with a note saying "this changes *just* the Python highlighting". Failing that, I'd settle for something in my `init.el`. I'd much rather have it packaged with the main color-theme, though.

Is this possible? Scratch that. This is Emacs; I *know* it's possible! But how can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be possible using [Face Remapping](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html). Even though you prefer to patch up the color-theme definition, I'd argue for putting something like the following lines into your `init.el` file, as it is a more "standard" way of doing such things:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'remap-builtin-face-blue)

(defun remap-builtin-face-blue ()
  (let ((blue "#2075c7"))
    (set (make-local-variable 'face-remapping-alist)
         `((font-lock-builtin-face :foreground ,blue)))))
```

Comment: That works very well! Thanks. The goal behind integrating it with the color-theme is so that it can work "out of the box" for anyone who installs the theme, without requiring them to modify their init.el. If that's not feasible, though, at least this gets the job done.

Comment: @Kirk: Good point, but not everybody might want to change the font like this. So you would have to add a customizable option or something to the theme, too, and then it wouldn't be "out of the box" either. I think adding stuff to your `init.el` is a very common thing to do, and Emacs user are familiar with it. After all, it's just copy & paste.

Comment: True, and perhaps just including a readme might be the best approach.